# ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence. What could be going wrong?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to implement the following code.

## GP Winners

```
driver_winner = df.loc[df['position_order']==1].groupby('driver') 
['position_order'].count().sort_values(ascending=False).to_frame().reset_index()
```

## Barplot

```
sns.barplot(data = driver_winner, y = 'driver', x = 'position_order', color = 'green', alpha = 
0.8)
plt.title('Most GP Winners in F1')
plt.ylabel('Driver Name')
plt.xlabel('Number of GP wins')
plt.yticks([])
```

But instead of getting the barplot I get the ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence.

Comment: Which line raises that error? What your data looks like?

Comment: Please show the full traceback, not just the error message. It's not enough to know *what* the error is, we need to know *where*. Don't ask us to guess.

Comment: But, given that I have to guess, my guess is that `driver_winner` is empty.

Comment: Sorry everyone for the imcomplete data. I'm a newbie. I'm trying to work on the project solved in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7v9puRHfelw and the dataset is available here https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rohanrao/formula-1-world-championship-1950-2020. The error happens on line 18. I don't get the barplot as shown in the video but get an error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.